# Algorithm to draw arrowhead at the end of arbitrary line in an Android custom View

Tags: android, algorithm, line-drawing

I've been trying to come up with an algorithm to draw an arrow in a custom View, using Path, but I haven't figured out how to get the coordinates of the arrowhead tips. The line startpoint and endpoint coordinates are arbitrary, the angle of the arrowhead relative to the line and the length of the arrowhead are fixed.

I think I have to use trigonometry somehow, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: maybe show what you tried so far so we could improve your effort

Comment: the problem with adding an image is the line can be at any angle

Comment: At least you can show a snippet of your code. :)

Comment: I haven't written code, I've been trying out various math equations on paper. None of them work

Comment: see PathMeasure class

Comment: No need for any math,  use the Matrix, Neo

Answer (score 0):

My friend came up with a math equation, which I have translated into java code here:

```
public static void calculateArrowHead(Point start, Point end, double angleInDeg, double tipLength){
    double x1 = end.getX();
    double x2 = start.getX();
    double y1 = end.getY();
    double y2 = start.getY();
    double alpha = Math.toRadians(angleInDeg);
    double l1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2-y1, 2)); // length of the arrow line
    double l2 = tipLength;

    double a = Math.pow(y2-y1, 2) + Math.pow(x2-x1, 2);
    double b = -2 * l1 * l2 * Math.cos(alpha) * (y2 - y1);
    double c = Math.pow(l1, 2) * Math.pow(l2, 2) * Math.pow(Math.cos(alpha), 2) - Math.pow(l2, 2) * Math.pow(x2-x1, 2);

    double s2a = (-b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
    double s2b = (-b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
    double s1a = (l1 * l2 * Math.cos(alpha) - s2a * (y2 - y1)) / (x2-x1);
    double s1b = (l1 * l2 * Math.cos(alpha) - s2b * (y2 - y1)) / (x2-x1);

    double x3a = s1a + x1;
    double y3a = s2a + y1;
    double x3b = s1b + x1;
    double y3b = s2b + y1;
    System.out.println("(A) x:" + (int)x3a + "; y:" + (int)y3a);
    System.out.println("(B) x:" + (int)x3b + "; y:" + (int)y3b);
}
```

I haven't tested it thoroughly, but for the first few tests, it appears to be correct.